# no route found for GET /media/image_test.png

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to display an image using `<%= img_tag("/media/image_test.png") %>`
the **image_test.png** is located in the folder "**media**" that is located on the root of my project folder named "practice".

But I'm getting **error no route found for GET /media/image_test.png**.

Below is the content of my files:

**practice/media/image_test.png**

> Image

**practice/lib/practice_web/templage/index.html.eex**

> `<%= img_tag("/media/1570573826060_.png") %>`

It's clear that the image path is not corect.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/media/1570573826060_.png") %>">
```

Try this one, you should access those with the static path

Comment: This only works if the file is in `/priv/static/media/1570573826060_.png` tho. It does not work for root paths.

Comment: @JonasDellinger I think by default Phoenix expects your static files to be in the `/assets` folder which then gets compiled into the `/priv` folder, so there no surprise it doesn't work from the root directory. Maybe there is a way to make Phoenix check the root directory too, you could start with reading the docs here -> https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Static.html